# C# : Return the selected elements in an Array in C#

Tags: c#

I need a method to return the select elements in a 1D array where the the position of the elements are stored in another array as follow:

```
double[] A = new double[11] { 8, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5};

Int32[] C = new Int32[3] { 1, 5, 8};

double[] B = MyMethod(A, C);
```

It should return:

```
{9, 6, 9}
```

I'm lost in Linq's Select, Where, Take :-)

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: If `C#` was more like `Fortran` you could do `B=A[C]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *linq*, all you would need to do is `Select` from the `Offset` array of `int` and *project* those `int` elements into the *indexer* of the source array

Here is a *generic* solution that will work with any type

**Given**

```
public static T[] SliceAndDice<T>(T[] source, int[] offsets)
   => offsets.Select(t => source[t]).ToArray();
```

**Usage**

```
var a = new double[11] { 8, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5 };

var b = new int[3] { 1, 5, 8 };

var results = SliceAndDice(a,b);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
9, 6, 9
```

If you need the brackets

```
Console.WriteLine($"{{{string.Join(", ", results)}}}");
```

**Output**

```
{9, 6, 9}
```

---

For a completely validated and checked extension method

```
public static T[] SliceAndDice<T>(this T[] source, int[] offsets)
{
   if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
   if (offsets == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(offsets));

   var result = new T[offsets.Length];

   for (var i = 0; i < offsets.Length; i++)
   {
      if(offsets[i] >= source.Length)
         throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index outside the bounds of the source array");
      result[i] = source[offsets[i]];
   } 

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the other answer, just stripped down to the bare minimum for an extension method.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] A = new double[] { 8, 9, 8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5 };
        double[] B = A.Slice(new[] { 1, 5, 8 } );            
    }

    public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] array, IEnumerable<int> index)
    {
        return index.Select((i) => array[i]).ToArray();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overload of LINQ `Where` extension method which uses index:

```cs
var x = A.Where((z, index) => C.Any(j => j == index));
```